# Is this expression bounded?

Tags: calculus, products, elementary-functions

I wonder: is
$$
\left( 1 + \frac{n}{a} \right)^{-a}
\prod_{k = 1}^n \left( 1 + \frac{a}{k} \right)
$$
uniformly bounded in $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $0 < a \leq n$?

Following Jack's answer, I have appended the restriction $a \leq n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the AM-GM inequality,
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{a}{k}\right)< \left(1+\frac{a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\right)^n<\exp\left(a H_n\right)$$
hence we just need to show that:
$$ H_n - \log\left(1+\frac{n}{a}\right) = H_n - \log(n+a)+\log(a)\tag{1} $$
is uniformly bounded in $n$. This follows from $\log(n+a)>\log n$ and:
$$ H_n \leq \log n +\gamma +\frac{1}{2n}. \tag{2}$$
However, for large $a$ the expression is expected to behave like $a^a$, hence we cannot have a uniform bound  with respect to $a$, too. Even if $a=n$, the expression equals:
$$ 2^{-n}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{n+k}{k} = 2^{-n}\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{2^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}\left(1+O\left(n^{-1/2}\right)\right).$$

Comment: what about $\log a$ in (1)?

Comment: @user66081: It does not depend on $n$ so it is for sure uniformly bounded.

Comment: why is it expected to behave like $a^a$?

Comment: Take logarithms and compute the asymptotic behaviour. The main contribute is given by $\exp(a\log a)=a^a.$

Comment: It also follows from the Euler product for the $\Gamma$ function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Comment: I think it is correct that the expression is not bdd for arbitrary large $a$; I have modified the Q slightly.

Comment: @user66081: even with that restriction, the expression is unbounded.